# Locating a sequence of 2D points in a set of polygons with holes

Tags: graphs, computational-geometry, polygons

Using the CGAL library, I am working on a 2D layout graph which contains an array of 2D polygons with holes. The aim is to generate random points (based on some conditions) and only keep the points inside the area of 2D polygons but not in their holes. The function I use for this is `CGAL::bounded_side_2`. Please see the CGAL documentation [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon/group__PkgPolygon2Functions.html).

Performing this for each point is very costly as I have more than 50,000 points. Is there a way to perform this operation in a parallel manner or speed up using some data structure?

Comment: Questions about specific pieces of software are probably better asked on a group like [computergraphics.SE], although check their FAQ first.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve, this problem is solved by using a [point-in-polygon test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) for each of the 50,000 points.  This should be efficient, even if performed on only a single machine.  To deal with polygon-shaped holes, check if the point is contained in the containing polygon and not in the hole; each can be checked with a separate point-in-polygon test.

How to do it with the CGAL library is an implementation matter that is best addressed in a CGAL support forum or on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

This question should be asked on the SO... But anyway:

1. Create a [CGAL 2D Arrangement](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/index.html) from your set of polygons with holes.
2. Mark faces of this arrangement, which you consider unwanted, by the `false` boolean value.
3. Call the function `CGAL::locate` on this arrangement and your array of random points, and keep the points, which got into faces with the mark `true`.

There are other functions in this CGAL package as well, so you can choose an algorithm, which works best for you.